# Pattern that adds a different value to the same attribute for many classes

Tags: sass

The purpose of this question is to get some advice for improving the following code in order to make it less repetitive.

```
.parent-div a {
  border-bottom: 10px solid;
  .blue & {
    border-color: $blue;
  }
  .red & {
    border-color: $red;
  }
  .green & {
    border-color: $green;
  }
  .pink & {
    border-color: $pink;
  }
  .yellow & {
    border-color: $yellow;
  }
  .purple & {
    border-color: $purple;
  }
  // here comes again all the styles but for each hovered anchor
 .blue &:hover {
    border-color: darken($blue, 10%);
  }
 .red &:hover {
     border-color: darken($red, 10%);   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can minimize your SASS code using [`@each`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive) and [`nesting`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#nested_rules) for `:hover`

```
.parent-div a {
  border-bottom: 10px solid;

  @each $color in blue, red, green, yellow, pink, purple { // Iterate through colors
    .#{$color} & {
      border-color: $color;

      &:hover { // Nested inside
        border-color: darken($color, 10%);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which compiles to the following output

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Manojkr/pen/LpgZgg)

```css
.parent-div a {
  border-bottom: 10px solid;
}
.blue .parent-div a {
  border-color: blue;
}
.blue .parent-div a:hover {
  border-color: #0000cc;
}
.red .parent-div a {
  border-color: red;
}
.red .parent-div a:hover {
  border-color: #cc0000;
}
.green .parent-div a {
  border-color: green;
}
.green .parent-div a:hover {
  border-color: #004d00;
}
.yellow .parent-div a {
  border-color: yellow;
}
.yellow .parent-div a:hover {
  border-color: #cccc00;
}
.pink .parent-div a {
  border-color: pink;
}
.pink .parent-div a:hover {
  border-color: #ff8da1;
}
.purple .parent-div a {
  border-color: purple;
}
.purple .parent-div a:hover {
  border-color: #4d004d;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <a href="#">Test</a>
</div>
<div class="blue">
  <div class="parent-div">
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="red">
  <div class="parent-div">
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="green">
  <div class="parent-div">
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="yellow">
  <div class="parent-div">
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pink">
  <div class="parent-div">
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="purple">
  <div class="parent-div">
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the above code seems to carry little logic. I think you were looking to nest the color classes after parent element like this:

```
.parent-div a {
  border-bottom: 10px solid;

  @each $color in blue, red, green, yellow, pink, purple { // Iterate through colors
     &.#{$color} {
      border-color: $color;

      &:hover { // Nested inside
        border-color: darken($color, 10%);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which would be logically correct and with better HTML and CSS syntax:

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Manojkr/pen/wKYWRK)

```css
.parent-div a {
  border-bottom: 10px solid;
}
.parent-div a.blue {
  border-color: blue;
}
.parent-div a.blue:hover {
  border-color: #0000cc;
}
.parent-div a.red {
  border-color: red;
}
.parent-div a.red:hover {
  border-color: #cc0000;
}
.parent-div a.green {
  border-color: green;
}
.parent-div a.green:hover {
  border-color: #004d00;
}
.parent-div a.yellow {
  border-color: yellow;
}
.parent-div a.yellow:hover {
  border-color: #cccc00;
}
.parent-div a.pink {
  border-color: pink;
}
.parent-div a.pink:hover {
  border-color: #ff8da1;
}
.parent-div a.purple {
  border-color: purple;
}
.parent-div a.purple:hover {
  border-color: #4d004d;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <a href="#">Test</a>
</div>
<div class="parent-div">
  <a class="blue" href="#">Test</a>
</div>
<div class="parent-div">
  <a class="red" href="#">Test</a>
</div>
<div class="parent-div">
  <a class="yellow" href="#">Test</a>
</div>
<div class="parent-div">
  <a class="green" href="#">Test</a>
</div>
<div class="parent-div">
  <a class="yellow" href="#">Test</a>
</div>
<div class="parent-div">
  <a class="pink" href="#">Test</a>
</div>
<div class="parent-div">
  <a class="purple" href="#">Test</a>
</div>
```